# Css transition not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

I have a scenario where on button click transition should happen.

These are the transitions which were applied. In chrome browser it is working good, but in IE11 when tried the transitions aren't getting applied.

I have applied CSS like below:

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition-property: right, left;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: right, left; /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
    -ms-transition-property: right, left; /* Safari */
    -ms-transition-duration: 2s; /* Safari */
    position:absolute;
    right:calc(100% - 100px);
}

div:hover{
    right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/291/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, IE11 has issues applying a `transition` to a property if one or both of its values are set using `calc`.

One workaround would be to set the second value of the calculation using a `transform`, however, the result may not match your desired animation completely. Note that the percentage used in the `translatex` function here is relative to the width of the element.

```css
div{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    transform:translatex(100%);
    transition-duration:2s;
    transition-property:right,transform;
}
div:hover{
    right:0;
    transform:translatex(0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use [calc()](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) (see `Known issues` tab):

> IE11 does not support transitioning values set with calc()

This example works:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition-property: right, left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -ms-transition-property: right, left;
    -ms-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: right, left;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    position: absolute;
    right: 80%;
}

div:hover {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/gyk9gqn4/1/)

Answer (score -1):

According to the compatibility table you don't need to use prefix `-ms-`.

> Chrome: no prefix for 26.0 for 4.0 use `-webkit-`
>
> IE: no prefix for 10.0
>
> Mozilla: no prefix for 16.0 for 4.0 use `-moz-`
>
> Safari: no prefix for 6.1 for 3.1 use `-webkit-`
>
> Opera 12.1 for 10.5 use `-o-`

Comment: write this and check into head section : <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=10;IE=Edge,chrome=1"/>

also try clearing cache before running code into browser.

Comment: that's strange i will let you know when i reach home and check in my IE11.

Comment: On my internet explorer it is running properly.