# CSS Transition not working in IE 11

Tags: css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-11

There is a similar question already here: [Css transition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804100/css-transition-not-working)

The problem is different. I do not use `calc()` anywhere, neither on the "broken" element nor any related to it.

I have a menu, for selecting the website's language, which I pushed beyond the right border by setting `margin-left: 100%;`. Clicking a checkbox should trigger it to fall back to `margin-left: initial;`, thus becoming visible to the user. Clicking the checkbox again, will make the menu disappear again (`margin-left: 100%;`).

There is a `transition: margin-left .4s` for both `margin-left` settings to make it more appealing to the user.

This setting works perfectly with Firefox and Chrome. The language selection slides in from the right, you can click the links for the respective language version and the menu slides out of the window smoothly. Perfectly what I intended.

However, it does not work with IE 11. The menu remains invisible. From reading the question linked above I reckoned it could be connected to not using fixed sizes for the menu. I changed that but to no avail.

In Firefox and Chrome clicking the checkbox triggers the menu to slide in and out of the window as intended. In IE11 the changes in the button's text (basically a `p` underneath the checkbox) are applied but the menu remains invisible.

**Additional Information**

Unlike in the question linked I do *not* use vendor prefixes. However, I tested what happens if I do so and also there I was unsuccessful. I does not seem to be linked to prefix issues either.

**Code**

This is the code of the element in question:

```css
#language-selection {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 65px;
 margin-left: 100%;
 transition: margin-left .4s;
}

#language-selection-checkbox:checked ~ #language-selection-wrapper #language-selection {
 margin-left: initial;
 transition: margin-left .4s;
}
```

Please also note that adding or removing `position: relative;` had absolutely no effect on the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment on my question! Yes, but I do not use `calc()`either on height or width. So the issue cannot be the same. I even tried to go by some of their solutions (as in: I applied fixed width and height, yet to no avail).

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @MrLister Sure! I edited, sorry for the omission in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial` value is not supported by IE , you can check it [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value), you can try other values, such as `auto` or any `length` you like

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the accepted answer as it perfectly works. I changed the code to `margin-left: 0;` and it works as intended in every browser, also IE11. The devil's in the detail... Thank you for pointing this out.